# Understand the code of xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I am trying to understand the code of xlwings, and stuck by [_xlmac.py](http://pydoc.net/Python/xlwings/0.2.3/xlwings._xlmac/).

For instance, for the following function

```
def get_value_from_range(xl_range):
    return xl_range.value.get()
```

I would like to know how the attribute `.value.` and the method `get()` are defined. Does anyone know the details?

**Edit 1**

Another example is the function `calculate` from this [version](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/blob/master/xlwings/_xlmac.py),

```
def calculate(xl_app):
    xl_app.calculate()
```

Does anyone know where to find details about the definition of the function `calculate`?

Comment: That's not a method; it's an attribute that has a method.  `get()` is the method.

Comment: Sure... so where is the method `get()` is defined?

Comment: `get_value_from_range()` is expecting some type of argument that has an attribute called `value` which itself has a `get` method.  There is no example of `get_value_from_range()` actually being used, however, so I can't tell you what that type is.

Comment: Then let's see if anyone else could tell from the package itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xlwings is using `appscript`(for the docs, see [here](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/doc/appscript-manual/index.html)).

Everything starting with `xl_` is an appscript object on Mac (on Windows it would be a pywin32 COM object), for example, `xl_app` is the following:

```
from appscript import app
xl_app = app('Microsoft Excel')
```

This means, you should check the docs about appscript to get more details. I also recommend you to look at the xlwings code on [GitHub](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings) instead of the link you provided (it's links to an old version).